# process.env.REACT_APP value ignored to be used as a component prop in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I made a lot of experiments to find out way is not working but no success at all..
Any idea what can be wrong?

```
  let smallerThan = process.env.REACT_APP_SMALLER_THAN;
  console.log('smallerThan', smallerThan);               // print 3, which is the right value given in .env
```

The value of `smallerThan` should be a variable default value with the possibility to be adjusted over the app provider (like render.com) in the server environment variables but is not forwarded to the component prop

```
 <ApexChart smallerThan={smallerThan} />
```

If I use

```
localStorage.setItem('smallerThan_Id', e.target.value);
let smallerThan = localStorage.getItem('smallerThan_Id');
```

or hard coded values is work well.

Comment: not sure why it doesnt work but my question is why are you even passing it as prop when you can access it anywhere in your app?

Comment: The value of smallerThan should be a variable default value with the possibility to be adjusted over the app provider (like render.com) in the server environment variables.

Comment: How do these code snippets work together? There is some info missing.

Comment: Why not access it directly from process.env? Why pass it to the prop? You can access it directly.

Comment: Because of the complex situation, I have to manage like: let smallerThan = localStorage.getItem('smallerThan_Id') || process.env.REACT_APP_SMALLER_THAN;